# Compute a Real Integral using Residue Theorem

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

My question is related to the computation of the integral:
$$I(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-iz~p}}{p^2}dp,$$
where $z\in \mathbb R$.

Using the Residue Theorem I found the solution: $I(z)=-|z|/2$. But when I checked the answer with mathematica it tells me that the integral does not converge...

I believe that either I did something wrong in the calculation or in the Mathematica input... So the question is (summarized as) does the above integral converge? If it does what is it's value?

Comment: You should do something about $p=0$.

Comment: @i707107 Well, I used the option for mathematica to find the Cauchy Principal value. Maybe if my "by hand" calculation is correct a moderator can migrate the question to mathematica.SE.

Comment: According to Maple, even the PV diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Hum, the plot thickens...

Comment: Just ignore the imaginary part, since there is no cancellation in the real part (the real part of the function is even).  The real part of the numerator is a cosine, which tends to 1 as $p \to 0$ so the real part of this thing is essentially indistinguishable from $\frac{1}{p^2}$ as $p \to 0$ and therefore this unambiguously diverges.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I agree with you, it's just weird that I got that result and I don't know where I made the mistake...
I just found [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3679v3.pdf) article; eq.(22) in page 9, the case d=1 is the result I found since this integral arises from computing the Green function in $\mathbb R$ using the Fourier transform method.

Comment: Not knowing all the steps leading up to this, my guess is that you need to consider whatever it is you're doing in the sense of tempered distributions on some appropriate function space, in which case you can make sense of the divergent integrals. That's usually (always, in my experience) the natural setting for these Green function computations, especially if you are using Fourier methods.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thank you, first of all, for the prompt response. Well, I'm reading the wiki article on Tempered distributions and it is quite cryptic to me but I'll study the subject for a while and hopefully I'll make sense of it. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: It's a pretty advanced subject to be honest; I don't know if it's worth trying to parse the wiki article.  The thing to remember here is that if you are ever trying to solve for a delta function with classical methods, then somewhere something is going to blow up.  This is just a general fact since there is no real function with the property that $\int f(t) \delta(x-t) dt = f(x)$ for all continuous $f$.  To make sense of that equation, somewhere you need to take limits and the setting for that is either the Schwarz space or the space of distributions.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I've found a reference ([here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch11.pdf) btw, for future readers) and I'm finding it quite clear and explains axactly what you said.
Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: Somehow and according to @ChrisJanjigian you were trying to calculate the Fourier Transform of the one dimensional Coulomb Potential. In Condensed Matter Physics, there is not any problem because small $q$ are responsible for collective excitations which are not necessary present in many cases. That means that the 'real' potential is somehow modified such that the real denominator is something like $q^2 + q_{c}^{2}$.

Comment: Indeed, you calculated something like $\displaystyle{\large\lim_{q \to 0}\left[{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}zp} \over p^2 + q^2}\,{\rm d}p - {1 \over 2q}\right] = -\,{\left\vert\,z\right\vert \over 2}}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Would you care to convert your (and Chris's) comments into an answer, seeing as they seem to form an adequate answer to the question?

Comment: @Lord_Farin That will be fine. I'll do it a little bit later. Thanks.